# HTCondor: reject job because of their own requirements

Tags: python, condor

I was wondering if there's any way to debug/improve on the messaging on why my job is being rejected. I'm currently submitting my jobs to a pool with a few GPUs on it. However, some of the jobs are rejected due to 'their own' requirements?

Is it at all possible to see what these requirements are? I've been using `condor_q -better -analyze` to print out some information. I did read somewhere that 'ownership' can be an issue where the machine is interacted with by someone and HTCondor will give full ownership to the physical user. Is it possible to show this somehow?

In some cases, my job will be shown as running within `condor_q` but will have no progress within the `output.log` file. So, there's a mismatch between what HTCondor says, and what my python script says. Is it at all possible to debug these so-called `ghost jobs` with HTCondor efficiently via command line?

My current `submit_file` is as follows,

```
executable = /usr/bin/python3
arguments  = ~/main.py

JobBatchName = test

# Event, out and error logs
log    = ~/logs/c$(cluster).p$(process).log
output = ~/logs/c$(cluster).p$(process).out
error  = ~/logs/c$(cluster).p$(process).error

should_transfer_files = YES
requirements = (CUDAGlobalMemoryMb > 6000) && (CUDAGlobalMemoryMb <  16000) && \
               (CUDACapability > 3.0) && (CUDADriverVersion >= 11) 
     
# Resources
request_GPUs     = 1
request_CPUs     = 1
request_memory   = 4G

#If the job doesn't run, blacklist the machine and try again. 
on_exit_remove = (ExitCode == 0)
job_machine_attrs = Machine   
job_machine_attrs_history_length = 10
requirements = $(requirements) && (target.machine =!= MachineAttrMachine1) && (target.machine =!= MachineAttrMachine2)

# Queue commands
queue
```

Thank you, any help is appreicated! :)

Edit:

Here's a job which is running. At the bottom, you see it says `10 reject your job because of their own requirements`, is there a way to exapnd upon what those requirements are? It's really vague, and I was wondering if I could expand upon it and modify my own requirements to ensure that more machines can run my jobs!

```
% condor_q 1574 -better -analyze


-- Schedd: pool.address.com : <ip_address_here?...
The Requirements expression for job 1574.0 is

    ((CUDAGlobalMemoryMb > 6000) && (CUDAGlobalMemoryMb < 17000) && (CUDACapability > 2.000000000000000E+00) && (CUDADriverVersion >= 11) &&
      (target.machine isnt MachineAttrMachine1) && (target.machine isnt MachineAttrMachine2)) && (TARGET.Arch == "X86_64") && (TARGET.OpSys == "LINUX") &&
    (TARGET.Disk >= RequestDisk) && (TARGET.Memory >= RequestMemory) && (TARGET.GPUs >= RequestGPUs) && (TARGET.HasFileTransfer)

Job 1574.0 defines the following attributes:

    DiskUsage = 4500
    MachineAttrMachine1 = "mach1.address.com"
    MachineAttrMachine2 = "mach2.address.com"
    RequestDisk = DiskUsage
    RequestGPUs = 1
    RequestMemory = 4096

The Requirements expression for job 1574.0 reduces to these conditions:

         Slots
Step    Matched  Condition
-----  --------  ---------
[0]        1305  CUDAGlobalMemoryMb > 6000
[5]        1741  CUDADriverVersion >= 11
[6]        1261  [0] && [5]
[7]        1864  target.machine isnt MachineAttrMachine1
[8]        1250  [6] && [7]
[9]        1872  target.machine isnt MachineAttrMachine2
[10]       1247  [8] && [9]
[17]        767  TARGET.Memory >= RequestMemory
[18]        460  [10] && [17]
[19]        332  TARGET.GPUs >= RequestGPUs
[20]        174  [18] && [19]


1574.0:  Job is running.

Last successful match: Tue Jun 22 11:28:19 2021


1574.0:  Run analysis summary ignoring user priority.  Of 34 machines,
    16 are rejected by your job's requirements
    10 reject your job because of their own requirements
      0 match and are already running your jobs
      0 match but are serving other users
     8 are able to run your job
```

Comment: Can you show the output of condor_q -better analyze?

Comment: HI @Greg, I've attached an edit with that! Thank you for the help! :)